# How to get parts of a string via regular expressions in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: regex, kotlin

Suppose you have a string `http://server.com/s123456` and want to get `123456` from it. Or `http://server.com/s123456&a=100` and get 123456, 100. Many different situations where you want to have parts of a string.

In order to match strings I use regular expressions.

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val text = "http://server.com/s123456" // Source string.
    val reg = "^http://server.com/s\\d+\$".toRegex()
    assertEquals(true, reg.matches(text))

    // Try to split the string with findAll().
    val a: Sequence<MatchResult> = reg.findAll(text, 0)
    val names = a.map { it.groupValues[0] }.joinToString()
    println(names) // http://server.com/s123456
}
```

But it doesn't split the source string into chars and digits, just prints: `http://server.com/s123456`. Is there a way to write a mask, so that we can retrieve numbers (or any other parts) from the string?

Comment: Im not familiar with kotlin, but You seems to not having groups. `"^http://server.com/s(\\d+)\$"` try this and use 1 in `groupValues` index.

Comment: @Eraklon, thanks, it works! Please, create an answer here, so that I could accept it.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capture group around the the part that you interested. Use this `"^http://server.com/s(\\d+)\$"` and use `it.groupValues[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try just `(\d+)`

Example (written in Python):

```
a = 'http://server.com/s123456'
b = 'http://server.com/s123456&a=100'
c = 'http://server.com/s122&&&'
d = 'http://server.com/s1234!56&a=100terere'
lis=[a,b,c,d]
for item in lis:
    print(re.findall(r'(\d+)', item ))
```

**output**

```
['123456']
['123456', '100']
['122']
['1234', '56', '100']
```

Comment: Thanks for `(\\d+)` and test cases!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Eraklon and @moys I wrote a similar answer.

```
@Test
fun test1() {
    val text = "http://server.com/s123456"
    val reg = "^http://server.com/s(\\d+)\$".toRegex()
    val a = reg.findAll(text, 0)
    val names = a.map { it.groupValues[1] }.joinToString()
    println(names) 
    // 123456
    assertEquals(true, reg.matches(text))
}

@Test
fun test2() {
    val a = "http://server.com/s123456"
    val b = "http://server.com/s123456&a=100"
    val c = "http://server.com/s122&&&"
    val d = "http://server.com/s1234!56&a=100terere"
    val e = "http://server.com/s"
    val f = "http://server.com"
    val reg = "(\\d+)".toRegex()

    val list = listOf(a, b, c, d, e, f)
    list.map { item ->
        val groups: Sequence<MatchResult> = reg.findAll(item, 0)
        val names = groups.map { it.groupValues[1] }.joinToString()
        println(names)
    }
    // Output:
    // 123456
    // 123456, 100
    // 122
    // 1234, 56, 100
    // 
    // 

    val groups: Sequence<MatchResult> = reg.findAll(e, 0)
    val names = groups.map { it.groupValues[1] }.firstOrNull()
    println(names)
    // null
}
```